# Has it ever been explained what Paul could have done to stop the Jihad?

Tags: dune

Throughout *Dune*, Paul has moments he calls nexus points where decisions he makes draw the Jihad he is trying to prevent closer. Some of these moments happen only after he has made a choice he doesn’t understand.

Has it ever been explained what these moments are and what Paul could have done?

In the book the only thing specified is where he realises he would need to kill himself, his mother and the 40 freeman he is with after the Jamis fight.

Comment: I have no facts to back this up but I would assume he would have become the God emperor instead of his son.